# python os.system как открыть/вывести консоль cmd с заданной строкой

Tags: python, консоль, cmd

```
import os

os.system("start cmd")  # открываем консоль и как туда передать определенную команду/строку 
                        # "cd c:\Users\Admin\"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615455/python-start-new-command-prompt-on-windows-and-wait-for-it-finish-exit>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через subprocess, что бы интерфейс консоли не запускался - используйте параметр shell = True

Пример: subprocess.call('Здесь cmd (batch) команда', shell = True)

Comment: Благодарю Вас мил человек )